# Laravel eloquent to join three table

Tags: php, laravel

Actually i'm facing problem in Laravel Eloquent to join three table where first table reference to second and second reference to third, the query is generated as

```
DB::table('factories')
                ->select('factories.order_id', 'factories.entry_date', 'factories.supplier_status', 'factories.remarks', 'orders.order_carpet_id', 'order_carpets.carpet_no')
                ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'factories.order_id')
                ->join('order_carpets', 'order_carpets.id', '=', 'orders.id')->get()
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I just wanna use this query from laravel eloquent orm

Comment: You want to create this query with Eloquent models?

Comment: yes i'm looking for this query with eloquent models

Comment: Can you add your models to the question?

Answer (score 0):

First, you haven't told us if you've already created your models or not.

If you haven't, you must create them first:

`php artisan make:model Factory`

`php artisan make:model Order`

`php artisan make:model Carpet`

I don't know from your code if `order_carpets` is meant to be an association/pivot table. If it is, then you just need an `Order` model and a `Carpet` model, you don't have to add a model for the pivot table, and you should add `belongsToMany()` on both the `Order` and `Carpet` models you created above.

Then you will be able to do:

`$carpet->orders` to get orders containing a particular carpet

and

`$order->carpets` to get carpets contained in a particular order.

Comment: Actually m not looking for this. I need help on how to write code as '$factories = Factory::where("entry_date", $date)->with("order")->get()' that also need reference of other model order_carpets where order_carpet_id and order_id is linked

Answer (score 0):

```
Factory::select('factories.order_id', 'factories.entry_date', 'factories.supplier_status', 'factories.remarks', 'orders.order_carpet_id', 'order_carpets.carpet_no')
                ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'factories.order_id')
                ->join('order_carpets', 'order_carpets.id', '=', 'orders.id')->get()
```

Will return a Factory model. If thats what youre looking for.

Comment: Actually m not looking for this. I need help on how to write code as
'$factories = Factory::where("entry_date", $date)->with("order")->get()'
that also need reference of other model order_carpets where order_carpet_id and order_id is linked

Comment: Im not sure what youre asking